# regEx is allowing letters inbetween numbers

Tags: php, javascript, regex, validation

Im trying to make some validation with javascript for a phone number field of a form.

I have taken some RegEx from another website and it almost works.

But the javascript does allow the form to submit if you place letters inbetween numbers like so "1234abc5678"

here is my validation code:

```
if (telephone==null || telephone=="")
  {
  alert("Telephone must be filled out");
  return false;
  }

var regexp = telephone.replace(/^[\s()+-]*([0-9][\s()+-]*){6,20}$/);
if (telephone.match(regexp))
  {
  alert("Telephone number is not valid");
  return false;
  }
```

Could someone help me with this code and tell me what is going wrong

After 1 more test I found that it allows letters within the numbers if I add a + at the beginning. I do need to allow the + at the start but obviously not the letters.

My required output would be for a phone number between 6 and 20 characters in length, which also allows a + at the start if one should be entered. any other characters should be invalid

Comment: And what you consider as valid phone number (what is desired output)? It will help.

Comment: edited the question to accommodate that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (telephone==null || telephone=="") {
    alert("Telephone must be filled out");
    return false;
}

var regexp = /^[\s()+-]*([0-9][\s()+-]*){6,20}$/;
if (! telephone.match(regexp)) {
    alert("Telephone number is not valid");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`replace` does not do what you think it does. just use

```
var regexp = /^[\s()+-]*([0-9][\s()+-]*){6,20}$/;
```

and you should be fine...

Comment: I also believe you want to use "is not true", because if it does match the regex, the phone number is valid.

if (! telephone.match(regexp)) {

Comment: @Branden Martin That was it! works like a charm now thank you very much :) put it in an answer and I will accept. Thankyou also Massa I did take you suggestion also

Answer (score 2):

Why are you calling `String#replace`? You just need to call `String#match(re)` like this:

```
var regex = /^[\s()+-]*([0-9][\s()+-]*){6,20}$/;
if (telephone.match(regex))
  console.log("Telephone number is valid");
else
  console.log("Telephone number is not valid");
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/urCGLV

Answer (score 2):

validate phone number with JavaScript

```
         var s ="123456";
        var filternumber = /^([0-9]+)$/;
        if((filternumber.test(s)==false)){
           alert ("not valid number");                
        }else {                               
          alert ("valid number");  
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to test

```
var regexp = telephone.replace(/^+?\d{6,20}$/);
if (!regexp.test(telephone))   {
    alert("Telephone number is not valid");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: ok, I did what you suggested but the problem is still there. no change at all :/